# Daylight bombing strategy

Tags: probability

Here is an excerpt from an article on daylight precision bombing:

> A heavy bomber at 20,000
>   feet had a 1.2 percent probability of
>   hitting a 100-foot-square target. About
>   220 bombers would be required for 90
>   percent probability of destroying the
>   target.

[Source](http://www.airforcemag.com/MagazineArchive/Documents/2008/October%202008/1008daylight.pdf)

How is the number of bombers calculated?

\begin{align*}
0.90 &= P(X \geq 1) \\
0.90 &= 1 - P(X = 0) \\
0.90 &= 1 - (1 - .012)^{k} \\
(1 - .012)^{k} &= 1 - 0.90 \\
k &= \log_{(1 - .012)} (1 - .90) \\
k &= \frac{\ln (1 - .90)}{\ln (1 - .012)}
\end{align*}

I get $k \approx 191$.

Comment: This looks correct to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got that as well. My reasoning was as follows: If $0.9$ is the probability of any of the bombers hitting, then $0.1$ is the probability of missing. A bomber misses with probability $0.988$ thus $k$ bombers miss with probability $0.988^k$.

$$0.988^k = 0.1 \iff k = \frac{\log{0.1}}{\log{0.988}} \approx 190.73$$